# How to stop getting e accent when I hit apostrophe

Tags: microsoft-word

I hit something that now makes accented vowels come up whenever I hit the apostrophe key. I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using a keyboard distribution that allows you to write international symbols. You may have pressed `Alt + Shift` accidentally to toggle it (try pressing those keys again and see if the behavior changes).

You can remove or change that distribution following the steps in this link: [How to change your keyboard layout](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/258824)

Comment: External links can break, in which case half of your answer would be lost.  Please include the essential information within the answer and use the link for attribution and further reading.  Thanks.